# vectorial functional equation

Tags: vectors, inner-products, functional-equations

I am trying to find the solutions of the following functional equation:

$-f(a+b, c, d) e^{a \cdot b}+f(a, b+c, d) e^{b \cdot c}-f(a, b, c+d) e^{c \cdot d}+f(a+d, b, c) e^{-a \cdot d}=0$

where $f(a, b, c)$ is a function of three vectors and is assumed to be Taylor expandable in terms of various scalar products of its arguments a, b, c (the output of $f$ is a scalar). In the equation, a, b, c, d are any vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

In addition, we define the scalar product as

$a \cdot b=a_{1} b_{2}-a_{2} b_{1}$
this means that $a \cdot b=-b \cdot a$, and $a \cdot a=0$ for all a, b in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$.

My ideas so far:

1. I managed to find some semi-trivial solutions which I am not interested in. Namely,

$f(a, b, c)=-g(a+b, c) e^{a \cdot b}+g(a, b+c) e^{b \cdot c}-g(a+c, b) e^{-a \cdot c}$

solves the above equation for any Taylor expandable function $g(a, b)$, but I am looking for other solutions.

2. I noticed that if I change the sign of $d$ in the last term, i.e.,
   $-f(a+b, c, d) e^{a \cdot b}+f(a, b+c, d) e^{b \cdot c}-f(a, b, c+d) e^{c \cdot d}+f(a-d, b, c) e^{a \cdot d}=0$

then a simple solution is
$f(a, b, c)=\exp [a \cdot b+a \cdot c+b \cdot c]$ which I am not sure if it is useful.

3. In two-dimension any three vectors are linearly dependent, in particular, we
   have the following identity for any a, b, c, d:

$(a \cdot b)(c \cdot d)+(b \cdot c)(a \cdot d)-(a \cdot c)(b \cdot d) \equiv 0$

Comment: Wouldn't that be the cross product, not the dot product? Also where does this functional equation come from?

Comment: Hi, @runway44. The cross product is a scalar in two dimensions. It is perfectly fine to define an inner product like the one above. Apparently this is an IMO (International Mathematics Olympiad) problem, but I don't know the year.

Comment: You have not defined an inner product, you have defined a symplectic form. Inner products are required to be symmetric or sesquilinear.

Comment: @runway44, yes you are right. we have a scalar product here.